# Postgres: Timestamp bigger than now

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I try to select all records of a table (Postgres DB) with the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE 'myTimestampRow' >= now()
```

There's allways an error message, telling me that there's an 'invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "myTimestampRow"'.

What's wrong with the above query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lose the single-quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE myTimestampRow >= now()
```

You can optionally double-quote column- and table-names, but no single-quotes; they will be interpreted as characters/strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
SELECT * FORM
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM
```

but that might be a typo in the question. I think your problem is the quoting of the columns,
it should read either

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestampRow >= now();
```

(no quotes) or

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "timestampRow" >= now();
```